# Convert Integer -> Char for a given Encoding

Tags: .net, character-encoding, stream

I'm looking at writing a little compiler. As part of this, I need to write some custom streams for things like pre-processing. I'm looking at inheriting from StreamReader.

With the StreamReader class you can specify an encoding to use. The Peek and Read functions return an integer value. I need to know how to convert these integer values into a char based upon this CurrentEncoding - and efficiently.

Thanks!

Comment: @vladimir StringReader takes a string as its input. I want to be able to nest streams on top of each other. For instance a file stream -> pre-processor stream -> tokenizer stream

Comment: if I right understood [the source code of StreamReader](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs) you shouldn't care about encoding because StreamReader manipulates just by an array of *char* (other words, just UTF 16 encoding). You need just cast *int* to *char*: "*var ch = (char)int_value*".

Comment: I'll give that a try. I'm using VB.NET for this project, so looks like there is a ChrW() function that converts integers to Unicode. It's unclear, though if that handles any and all encodings - since the different Unicode encodings encode things differently...

Comment: StreamReader can accept text file [differently encodes](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L473) (such as Big/Little Endian Unicode, UTF8, etc) but stores content as array of [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8) (UTF16).

Comment: @vladimir Ah, I see. Very helpful being able to peek into the source code. If you submit an answer I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StreamReader can accept text file [differently encodes](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs#L473) (such as Big/Little Endian Unicode, UTF8, etc) but stores content as array of [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8) (UTF16).

So just cast int to char:

```cs
var ch = (char)int_value;
```